# C# Reading a console application in a loop

Tags: c#

I need to execute my console app for many files in a loop and update my GUI. When I execute my app for the first time everything is ok, GUI updates are done in realtime. But with every iteration, reading of console output get longer delay. After 3-4 files I get only few updates or no updates at all. Its not a problem with updating GUI, my dataraceivedevent doesn't fire up.

I can't understand why, because after every iteration I close and dispose my process.

This is the method that I execute in the for-loop.

```
public void execute(string arguments, string path)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        myProcess.Start();
        myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(this.updateProgress);
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.CancelOutputRead();
        myProcess.OutputDataReceived -= updateProgress;
        myProcess.Close();
        myProcess.Dispose();

        if (progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar1.PerformStep();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
        }

        if (progressBar2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            progressBar2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                progressBar2.Value = 100;
                progressBar2.Refresh();
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            progressBar2.Value = 100;
            progressBar2.Refresh();
        }

        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Text = " ";
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Text = " ";
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem after executing 100K times, for the last time the `myProcess.WaitForExit();` took so much time. Instead, you can use the other overload which takes an integer indicating how many milliseconds the process has time to exit.
`myProcess.WaitForExit(1000);`

Comment: The problem is sometimes I need to wait one hour and sometimes only few minutes. Constant time value is not a solution for me.

Comment: You might want to look at this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx
"The code example avoids a deadlock condition by calling p.StandardError.ReadToEnd before p.WaitForExit. A deadlock condition can result if the parent process calls p.WaitForExit before p.StandardError.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to fill the redirected stream. The parent process would wait indefinitely for the child process to exit. The child process would wait indefinitely for the parent to read from the full StandardError stream."

Answer (score 0):

Please call `.BeginOutputReadLine();` method after `.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(...);`

probably `OutputDataReceived` event is happening before you start to read (before you attached the event)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx

like:

```
    myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(this.updateProgress);
    myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Killing my process doesn't make any difference.